# What does the "Cancelled recovery" status mean?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, terminology, airport-terminals

I noticed a flight with the status "Cancelled recovery" on the Spokane airport website. What does that mean?

I saw that the flight got diverted back to its original departure airport, but I don't understand what the recovery refers to.

---

"Cancelled recovery" status on the [Spokane airport website](https://spokaneairports.net/flight-status):

[image: ﬁ]

The flight got diverted back to its original departure airport:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Recovery](http://tracker.flightview.com/fvaccess/common/StatusDescriptions.html) means that a diverted flight has returned (or is en route) to its original departure point.

The flight in question from Phoenix/PHX to Spokane/GEG had taken off, but its arrival was cancelled (probably due to the weather conditions at GEG), and the plane returned to its departure point (PHX).